# Handling windows authentication while accessing url using requests

Tags: python, python-requests, python-3.4

I am using python request library to access the soap requests. And it was working fine. As there is change in our domain structure. I could not access the url, it always prompting me to enter the credentials.

[image]

I am using below code to access the url earlier using requests.

```
program_list_response = requests.get(program_list_path,
                                                 data=self.body, headers=self.headers)
```

How to pass the authentication in background  using requests?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use the [Authentication](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/authentication/#basic-authentication) feature for that in order to provide the credentials for the link that you want to access.

For an eg:

You can pass the username and password by using the below format:

```
requests.get('https://website.com/user', auth=('user', 'pass'))
```

For more details I would recommend the [official docs](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/authentication/#authentication).

For handling the Windows authentication then I would recommend the [Requests-NTLM](https://github.com/requests/requests-ntlm).

For eg:

```
import requests
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth

requests.get("http://ntlm_protected_site.com",auth=HttpNtlmAuth('domain\\username','password'))
```

Comment: Keep in mind all the different authentication methods, e.g. although the device I was trying to access was basic and the interface looked like it, I needed the `auth=HTTPDigestAuth('user', 'pass')`

Comment: For future people looking at this, I've spent a while looking around at different options and the `HttpNtlmAuth` solution was the only one that worked for me.

Comment: To expand on this topic, if you are already logged into a domain, and don't want to keep the username and password stored in your script, use [requests-negotiate-sspi](https://github.com/brandond/requests-negotiate-sspi) instead of requests_ntlm

Comment: @rayzinnz Excellent suggestion - this was exactly what I was searching for. It's actually a PyPi project, as well, and can be installed via pip: https://pypi.org/project/requests-negotiate-sspi