# How to perform HTTP Put Request in Python like C# HttpClient

Tags: python, c#, https, python-requests, http-put

I have the following code in C# that works perfectly at authenticating the user (reponse 200):

```
using (var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler { UseDefaultCredentials = true }))
{
HttpResponseMessage response = client.PutAsync(url,content).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

I want to do the same thing natively in Python, though the asynchronous call isn't important to me. I've tried:

```
import requests
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
r = requests.put(my_url,my_unicode_object,headers=headers,verify=False,auth=(username,pass))
```

However I get a 401 unauthorized response. I have all my C# variables to compare side-by-side and I still don't know how to get the same working in Python.

**Update:**
In VS when I type "System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials" I get the following:

```
Domain: ""
Password: ""
SecurePassword: {System.Security.SecureString}
UserName: ""
```

I don't think it's actually using any credentials, but with I try not using auth or auth = ('','') the http put request still gives a 401 request response.

Comment: the magic is `UseDefaultCredentials`. i think your c# code won't work on a clean machine.

Comment: how can I get and use default credentials with Python? At least, in the python auth I specify the same credentials I use to logon to windows. Can I examine the C# client object in some way to verify -or find an analogous method in Python to lookup the same? Of course, I know it's easier for .NET.

Comment: may i know what credential the url is using? is it active directory? i searched and found [HttpNtlmAuth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32305668/1518100). i never tried. but you can have a try.